# I can't find the button via Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, automation, nosuchelementexception

I've tried to find it through cssSelector and xPath but displays `NoSuchElementException` anyway

```java
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class='btn btn-primary c-schedule-story-button ']"));
element.click();
```

[Screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6VcM.jpg)

Comment: @tgdavies this is a valid CSS selector, they just don't use .  for classes and link to a web element using 'class' as an attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button..c-schedule-story-button"));
element.click();
```

Its inside an iframe , you have to switch to that first

you have to switch to defaultcontent if you want to interact again with outside elements

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent()
```

Comment: Anyway test fails.

Comment: whats the error

Comment: Updated the answer your class looks wrong than what i saw in the website

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element

Comment: i updared the answer try the new locator

Comment: thx. Your edited solution works

Comment: @Noob please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign near to the answer